# image not found with @rpath/libpoppler.71.dylib

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, conda, gdal, osgeo

Currently I've installed anaconda.
I'm trying to call in my script the osgeo.ogr module to open a shapefile but I have the following error:

> ImportError:
>   dlopen(/Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/osgeo/_gdal.cpython-36m-darwin.so,
>   2): Library not loaded: @rpath/libpoppler.71.dylib   Referenced from:
>   /Applications/anaconda3/lib/libgdal.20.dylib   Reason: image not found

I installed gdal through conda.

This is the list of conda packages:

```
Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
_ipyw_jlab_nb_ext_conf    0.1.0            py36h2fc01ae_0  
_r-mutex                  1.0.0               anacondar_1  
alabaster                 0.7.10           py36h174008c_0  
anaconda-client           1.6.14                   py36_0  
anaconda-navigator        1.8.4                    py36_0  
anaconda-project          0.8.2            py36h9ee5d53_0  
appnope                   0.1.0            py36hf537a9a_0  
appscript                 1.0.1            py36h9e71e49_1  
asn1crypto                0.24.0                   py36_0  
astroid                   1.6.3                     <pip>
astroid                   1.6.1                    py36_0  
astropy                   2.0.3            py36h1de35cc_0  
attrs                     17.4.0                   py36_0  
babel                     2.5.3                    py36_0  
backports                 1.0              py36ha3c1827_1  
backports.shutil_get_terminal_size 1.0.0            py36hd7a2ee4_2  
beautifulsoup4            4.6.0            py36h72d3c9f_1  
bitarray                  0.8.1            py36h1de35cc_1  
bkcharts                  0.2              py36h073222e_0  
blaze                     0.11.3           py36h02e7a37_0  
bleach                    2.1.3                     <pip>
bleach                    2.1.2                    py36_0  
bokeh                     0.12.13          py36h2f9c1c0_0  
boost                     1.66.0                   py36_1    conda-forge
boost-cpp                 1.66.0                        1    conda-forge
boto                      2.48.0           py36hdbc59ac_1  
bottleneck                1.2.1            py36hbd380ad_0  
bzip2                     1.0.6                hd86a083_4  
ca-certificates           2018.03.07                    0    anaconda
cairo                     1.14.10                       0    conda-forge
certifi                   2018.4.16                 <pip>
certifi                   2018.4.16                py36_0    anaconda
cffi                      1.11.4           py36h342bebf_0  
chardet                   3.0.4            py36h96c241c_1  
click                     6.7              py36hec950be_0  
cloudpickle               0.5.2                    py36_1  
clyent                    1.2.2            py36hae3ad88_0  
colorama                  0.3.9            py36hd29a30c_0  
conda                     4.4.10                   py36_0  
conda-build               3.4.1                    py36_0  
conda-env                 2.6.0                h36134e3_0  
conda-verify              2.0.0            py36he837df3_0  
contextlib2               0.5.5            py36hd66e5e7_0  
cryptography              2.1.4            py36h842514c_0  
curl                      7.58.0               ha441bb4_0  
cycler                    0.10.0           py36hfc81398_0  
cyrus-sasl                2.1.26               ha054001_1  
cython                    0.27.3           py36h6ecb376_0  
cytoolz                   0.9.0            py36h1de35cc_0  
dask                      0.16.1                   py36_0  
dask-core                 0.16.1                   py36_0  
datashape                 0.5.4            py36hfb22df8_0  
dbus                      1.11.0                        0    conda-forge
decorator                 4.2.1                    py36_0  
decorator                 4.3.0                     <pip>
distributed               1.20.2                   py36_0  
Django                    2.0.5                     <pip>
docutils                  0.14             py36hbfde631_0  
entrypoints               0.2.3            py36hd81d71f_2  
et_xmlfile                1.0.1            py36h1315bdc_0  
expat                     2.2.5                hb8e80ba_0  
fastcache                 1.0.2            py36h1de35cc_2  
filelock                  2.0.13           py36hf9de95b_0  
flask                     0.12.2           py36h5658096_0  
flask-cors                3.0.3            py36h7387b97_0  
font-ttf-dejavu-sans-mono 2.37                 h6964260_0  
font-ttf-inconsolata      2.001                hcb22688_0  
font-ttf-source-code-pro  2.030                h7457263_0  
font-ttf-ubuntu           0.83                 h8b1ccd4_0  
fontconfig                2.12.6               h9850fc5_0  
fonts-anaconda            1                    h8fa9717_0  
freetype                  2.8.1                         0    conda-forge
freexl                    1.0.5                h1de35cc_0  
fribidi                   1.0.2                h1de35cc_0  
gdal                      2.2.2            py36hd505dc6_1    anaconda
geojson                   2.3.0                     <pip>
geos                      3.6.2                h5470d99_2  
geotiff                   1.4.2                         1    conda-forge
get_terminal_size         1.0.0                h7520d66_0  
gettext                   0.19.8.1             h15daf44_3  
gevent                    1.2.2            py36ha70b9d6_0  
giflib                    5.1.4                h1035379_1  
glib                      2.55.0                        0    conda-forge
glob2                     0.6              py36h94c9186_0  
gmp                       6.1.2                hb37e062_1  
gmpy2                     2.0.8            py36hf9c35bd_2  
graphite2                 1.3.11               h337f25e_1  
greenlet                  0.4.12           py36hf09ba7b_0  
gsl                       2.4                  h3efe00b_3  
h5py                      2.7.1            py36h39cdac5_0  
harfbuzz                  1.7.6                         0    conda-forge
hdf4                      4.2.13               h39711bb_2  
hdf5                      1.10.1               ha036c08_1  
heapdict                  1.0.0                    py36_2  
html5lib                  1.0.1            py36h2f9c1c0_0  
icu                       58.2                 h4b95b61_1  
idna                      2.6              py36h8628d0a_1  
imageio                   2.2.0            py36h5e01289_0  
imagesize                 0.7.1            py36h3495948_0  
imagesize                 1.0.0                     <pip>
intel-openmp              2018.0.0             h8158457_8  
ipykernel                 4.8.0                    py36_0  
ipython                   6.2.1            py36h3dda519_1  
ipython_genutils          0.2.0            py36h241746c_0  
ipywidgets                7.1.1                    py36_0  
isort                     4.2.15           py36hceb2a01_0  
isort                     4.3.4                     <pip>
itsdangerous              0.24             py36h49fbb8d_1  
jbig                      2.1                  h4d881f8_0  
jdcal                     1.3              py36h1986823_0  
jedi                      0.12.0                    <pip>
jedi                      0.11.1                   py36_0  
jinja2                    2.10             py36hd36f9c5_0  
jpeg                      9b                   he5867d9_2  
json-c                    0.12.1               h6b7fe83_2  
jsonschema                2.6.0            py36hb385e00_0  
jupyter                   1.0.0                    py36_4  
jupyter_client            5.2.2                    py36_0  
jupyter_console           5.2.0            py36hccf5b1c_1  
jupyter_core              4.4.0            py36h79cf704_0  
jupyterlab                0.31.5                   py36_0  
jupyterlab_launcher       0.10.2                   py36_0  
kealib                    1.4.7                hc1e10f3_5  
krb5                      1.14.2               h9a779f2_6  
lazy-object-proxy         1.3.1            py36h2fbbe47_0  
libboost                  1.65.1               hcc95346_4  
libcurl                   7.58.0               hf30b1f0_0  
libcxx                    4.0.1                h579ed51_0  
libcxxabi                 4.0.1                hebd6815_0  
libdap4                   3.19.0               hefe82ba_2    anaconda
libedit                   3.1                  hb4e282d_0  
libffi                    3.2.1                h475c297_4  
libgdal                   2.2.2                h3559a57_1    anaconda
libgfortran               3.0.1                h93005f0_2  
libiconv                  1.15                 hdd342a3_7  
libkml                    1.3.0                hc0cae1e_3  
libnetcdf                 4.4.1.1              hdf03fd4_8    anaconda
libntlm                   1.4                  h1de35cc_2  
libpng                    1.6.34               he12f830_0  
libpq                     10.3                 hf30b1f0_0  
libsodium                 1.0.15               hd9e47c5_0  
libspatialite             4.3.0a              h0a2fa02_18  
libssh2                   1.8.0                h322a93b_4  
libtiff                   4.0.9                h0dac147_0  
libuuid                   1.0.3                h6bb4b03_2  
libxml2                   2.9.7                hab757c2_0  
libxslt                   1.1.32               hb819dd2_0  
llvm-openmp               4.0.1                hda82c8b_0  
llvmlite                  0.21.0           py36hff739e7_0  
locket                    0.2.0            py36hca03003_1  
lxml                      4.1.1            py36hef8c89e_1  
lzo                       2.10                 h362108e_2  
markupsafe                1.0              py36h3a1e703_1  
matplotlib                2.1.2            py36h6d6146d_0  
mccabe                    0.6.1            py36hdaeb55d_0  
mistune                   0.8.3                    py36_0  
mkl                       2018.0.1             hfbd8650_4  
mkl-service               1.1.2            py36h7ea6df4_4  
mpc                       1.0.3                h7a72875_5  
mpfr                      3.1.5                h711e7fd_2  
mpmath                    1.0.0            py36hf1b8295_2  
msgpack-python            0.5.1            py36h04f5b5a_0  
multipledispatch          0.4.9            py36hc5f92b5_0  
navigator-updater         0.1.0            py36h7aee5fb_0  
nbconvert                 5.3.1            py36h810822e_0  
nbformat                  4.4.0            py36h827af21_0  
ncurses                   6.0                  hd04f020_2  
networkx                  2.1                      py36_0  
nltk                      3.2.5            py36h1190bce_0  
nose                      1.3.7            py36h73fae2b_2  
notebook                  5.4.0                    py36_0  
numba                     0.36.2          np114py36hc2f221f_0  
numexpr                   2.6.4            py36habcfcfe_0  
numpy                     1.14.0           py36h8a80b8c_1  
numpydoc                  0.8.0                     <pip>
numpydoc                  0.7.0            py36he54d08e_0  
odo                       0.5.1            py36hc1af34a_0  
olefile                   0.45.1                   py36_0  
openjpeg                  2.3.0                h9b27163_0  
openpyxl                  2.4.10                   py36_0  
openssl                   1.0.2o               h26aff7b_0    anaconda
packaging                 17.1                      <pip>
packaging                 16.8             py36he5e8135_0  
pandas                    0.22.0           py36h0a44026_0  
pandoc                    1.19.2.1             ha5e8f32_1  
pandocfilters             1.4.2            py36h3b0b094_1  
pango                     1.40.14                       0    conda-forge
parso                     0.2.0                     <pip>
parso                     0.1.1            py36hc90e01c_0  
partd                     0.3.8            py36hf5c4cb8_0  
path.py                   10.5             py36h7bcb313_0  
pathlib2                  2.3.0            py36h877a6d8_0  
patsy                     0.5.0                    py36_0  
pcre                      8.41                 hfb6ab37_1  
pep8                      1.7.1                    py36_0  
pexpect                   4.3.1                    py36_0  
pickleshare               0.7.4            py36hf512f8e_0  
pika                      0.11.2                    <pip>
pillow                    5.0.0            py36hfcce615_0  
pip                       9.0.1            py36h1555ced_4  
pip                       10.0.1                    <pip>
pixman                    0.34.0               hca0a616_3  
pkginfo                   1.4.1            py36h25bf955_0  
pluggy                    0.6.0            py36hb1d0581_0  
ply                       3.10             py36h10e714e_0  
poppler                   0.61.1                        3    conda-forge
poppler-data              0.4.8                hf2eda46_0  
proj4                     4.9.3                h3f1bf9d_7  
prompt_toolkit            1.0.15           py36haeda067_0  
psutil                    5.4.5                     <pip>
psutil                    5.4.3            py36h1de35cc_0  
ptyprocess                0.5.2            py36he6521c3_0  
py                        1.5.2            py36ha69170d_0  
pycodestyle               2.3.1            py36h83e8646_0  
pycodestyle               2.4.0                     <pip>
pycosat                   0.6.3            py36hee92d8f_0  
pycparser                 2.18             py36h724b2fc_1  
pycrypto                  2.6.1            py36h1de35cc_7  
pycurl                    7.43.0.1         py36hdbc3d79_0  
pyflakes                  1.6.0            py36hea45e83_0  
pygments                  2.2.0            py36h240cd3f_0  
pylint                    1.8.4                     <pip>
pylint                    1.8.2                    py36_0  
pyodbc                    4.0.22           py36h0a44026_0  
pyopenssl                 17.5.0           py36h51e4350_0  
pyparsing                 2.2.0            py36hb281f35_0  
pyqt                      5.6.0            py36he5c6137_6  
PyQt5                     5.9.2                     <pip>
pysocks                   1.6.7            py36hfa33cec_1  
pytables                  3.4.2            py36hfbd7ab0_2  
pytest                    3.3.2                    py36_0  
python                    3.6.4                hc167b69_1  
python-dateutil           2.6.1            py36h86d2abb_1  
python.app                2                py36h54569d5_7  
pytz                      2017.3           py36hf0bf824_0  
pytz                      2018.4                    <pip>
pywavelets                0.5.2            py36h2710a04_0  
pyyaml                    3.12             py36h2ba1e63_1  
pyzmq                     17.0.0                    <pip>
pyzmq                     16.0.3           py36he48b5ad_0  
qt                        5.6.2               h9975529_14  
qtawesome                 0.4.4            py36h468c6fb_0  
qtconsole                 4.3.1            py36hd96c0ff_0  
QtPy                      1.4.0                     <pip>
qtpy                      1.3.1            py36h16bb863_0  
r-assertthat              0.2.0            r342hacfac53_0  
r-backports               1.1.1            r342h894203a_0  
r-base                    3.4.2                hc151561_0  
r-base64enc               0.1_3            r342h0880998_4  
r-bh                      1.65.0_1         r342hc3f23d0_0  
r-bindr                   0.1              r342hb4d41c9_0  
r-bindrcpp                0.2              r342h94b3c25_0  
r-bit                     1.1_12           r342hf8cc2cf_0  
r-bit64                   0.9_7            r342h1cba8d6_0  
r-bitops                  1.0_6            r342he7499e7_4  
r-blob                    1.1.0            r342h4b1ee69_0  
r-boot                    1.3_20           r342hfe7f006_0  
r-broom                   0.4.2            r342hfe0d134_0  
r-caret                   6.0_77           r342h513a81f_0  
r-catools                 1.17.1           r342hb039934_4  
r-cellranger              1.1.0            r342h50a9fb7_0  
r-class                   7.3_14           r342h43a4a0f_4  
r-cluster                 2.0.6            r342h26ab8c6_0  
r-codetools               0.2_15           r342h7db7eef_0  
r-colorspace              1.3_2            r342h18bddb6_0  
r-config                  0.2              r342ha2bb319_0  
r-crayon                  1.3.4            r342hdefe7e4_0  
r-curl                    3.0              r342ha80850a_0  
r-cvst                    0.2_1            r342hce93a4b_0  
r-data.table              1.10.4_1         r342he1ac18a_0  
r-dbi                     0.7              r342h6aefa47_0  
r-dbplyr                  1.1.0            r342h9881601_0  
r-ddalpha                 1.3.1            r342h4276367_0  
r-deoptimr                1.0_8            r342h88b17ca_0  
r-dichromat               2.0_0            r342hcb53b06_4  
r-digest                  0.6.12           r342h7ffa501_0  
r-dimred                  0.1.0            r342hcdfbb48_0  
r-dplyr                   0.7.4            r342hd462e57_0  
r-drr                     0.0.2            r342h1687f97_0  
r-essentials              1.7.0            r342h8f48fb2_0  
r-evaluate                0.10.1           r342h084298f_0  
r-forcats                 0.2.0            r342hfffa16c_0  
r-foreach                 1.4.3            r342he26c63b_4  
r-foreign                 0.8_69           r342hd19c61e_0  
r-formatr                 1.5              r342h8f6a739_0  
r-ggplot2                 2.2.1            r342hab9d682_0  
r-gistr                   0.4.0            r342h701b2b4_0  
r-glmnet                  2.0_13           r342h4f2bcf4_0  
r-glue                    1.1.1            r342hfa53b3f_0  
r-gower                   0.1.2            r342h52ab46c_0  
r-gtable                  0.2.0            r342h50414d9_0  
r-haven                   1.1.0            r342h706d249_0  
r-hexbin                  1.27.1           r342h5ebf162_4  
r-highr                   0.6              r342h042980c_0  
r-hms                     0.3              r342hdcc9ba2_0  
r-htmltools               0.3.6            r342h6918481_0  
r-htmlwidgets             0.9              r342h3fbdbc0_0  
r-httpuv                  1.3.5            r342hf739786_0  
r-httr                    1.3.1            r342h7338272_0  
r-ipred                   0.9_6            r342hca986ca_0  
r-irdisplay               0.4.4            r342h7974c32_0  
r-irkernel                0.8.9            r342hb51cc2a_0  
r-iterators               1.0.8            r342h797f5cf_4  
r-jsonlite                1.5              r342h0df1ae0_0  
r-kernlab                 0.9_25           r342h16d16b8_0  
r-kernsmooth              2.23_15          r342hf8f9fa8_4  
r-knitr                   1.17             r342h398035c_0  
r-labeling                0.3              r342h3f609a7_4  
r-lattice                 0.20_35          r342he33934a_0  
r-lava                    1.5.1            r342h38a1d13_0  
r-lazyeval                0.2.0            r342hda2787d_0  
r-lubridate               1.6.0            r342h21d6fc3_0  
r-magrittr                1.5              r342hc800aed_4  
r-maps                    3.2.0            r342hfd4408e_0  
r-markdown                0.8              r342hfbdeedd_0  
r-mass                    7.3_47           r342h998d679_0  
r-matrix                  1.2_11           r342hb831790_0  
r-mgcv                    1.8_22           r342hf92f93b_0  
r-mime                    0.5              r342h0f88ab8_0  
r-miniui                  0.1.1            r342hdb62d8b_0  
r-mnormt                  1.5_5            r342h42fb15d_0  
r-modelmetrics            1.1.0            r342hab8440a_0  
r-modelr                  0.1.1            r342h8b7c8fd_0  
r-mongolite               1.2              r342hfcc6d1d_0  
r-munsell                 0.4.3            r342h51b9f01_0  
r-nlme                    3.1_131          r342hbc0088b_0  
r-nnet                    7.3_12           r342hf39805f_0  
r-numderiv                2016.8_1         r342ha7fd6f4_0  
r-odbc                    1.1.2            r342h198ff3f_0  
r-openssl                 0.9.7            r342hf1585dd_0  
r-packrat                 0.4.8_1          r342h0db0e49_0  
r-pbdzmq                  0.2_6            r342h9ee0924_0  
r-pkgconfig               2.0.1            r342h037cecb_0  
r-pki                     0.1_5.1          r342hcf715fe_0  
r-plogr                   0.1_1            r342he1be899_0  
r-plyr                    1.8.4            r342h66d2667_0  
r-prodlim                 1.6.1            r342h1e7dc4e_0  
r-profvis                 0.3.3            r342hccd696e_0  
r-pryr                    0.1.2            r342ha062742_0  
r-psych                   1.7.8            r342he3dbd94_0  
r-purrr                   0.2.3            r342h7646bf1_0  
r-quantmod                0.4_11           r342ha084b29_0  
r-r6                      2.2.2            r342hd083555_0  
r-randomforest            4.6_12           r342h0f92a3f_4  
r-rappdirs                0.3.1            r342hb97dc51_0  
r-rbokeh                  0.5.0            r342h999a230_0  
r-rcolorbrewer            1.1_2            r342h009296c_0  
r-rcpp                    0.12.13          r342hd23d99a_0  
r-rcpproll                0.2.2            r342h72fe326_0  
r-rcurl                   1.95_4.8         r342h15ade9d_0  
r-readr                   1.1.1            r342h26b7cb6_0  
r-readxl                  1.0.0            r342h7fee92c_0  
r-recipes                 0.1.0            r342h9fa1523_0  
r-recommended             3.4.2                h1751db4_0  
r-rematch                 1.0.1            r342he4866fc_0  
r-repr                    0.12.0           r342hbf08d7a_0  
r-reshape2                1.4.2            r342h4e0c23c_0  
r-rjava                   0.9_9            r342h988b9d2_0  
r-rjdbc                   0.2_5            r342hbfbe204_0  
r-rjsonio                 1.3_0            r342h3e65b66_4  
r-rlang                   0.1.2            r342h6f7de11_0  
r-rmarkdown               1.6              r342hccf1f8e_2  
r-robustbase              0.92_7           r342h0705e89_0  
r-rpart                   4.1_11           r342h056d3ea_0  
r-rprojroot               1.2              r342h961df13_0  
r-rsconnect               0.8.5            r342hdc95913_0  
r-rstudioapi              0.7              r342hf20c2a2_0  
r-rvest                   0.3.2            r342h498b3d2_0  
r-scales                  0.5.0            r342h4ec2787_0  
r-selectr                 0.3_1            r342h1005dde_0  
r-sfsmisc                 1.1_1            r342hd831c0a_0  
r-shiny                   1.0.5            r342hb27b129_0  
r-sourcetools             0.1.6            r342h35ff172_0  
r-sparklyr                0.6.3            r342h4912c76_0  
r-spatial                 7.3_11           r342h4b9b681_4  
r-stringi                 1.1.5            r342ha83ea67_0  
r-stringr                 1.2.0            r342h61359ef_0  
r-survival                2.41_3           r342h7e0d132_0  
r-tibble                  1.3.4            r342h9aabc0a_0  
r-tidyr                   0.7.1            r342h953b3d9_0  
r-tidyselect              0.2.2            r342h4fcf255_0  
r-tidyverse               1.1.1            r342hf375f76_0  
r-timedate                3012.100         r342h8f8ad6e_4  
r-ttr                     0.23_2           r342h9ffbca2_0  
r-uuid                    0.1_2            r342h22fb745_4  
r-viridislite             0.2.0            r342h93fb38b_0  
r-withr                   2.0.0            r342hd7b5462_0  
r-xml2                    1.1.1            r342h289a617_0  
r-xtable                  1.8_2            r342hb9d8108_0  
r-xts                     0.10_0           r342h37a3a43_4  
r-yaml                    2.1.14           r342he3890bd_0  
r-zoo                     1.8_0            r342hf4683db_0  
readline                  7.0                  hc1231fa_4  
requests                  2.18.4           py36h4516966_1  
rope                      0.10.7           py36h68959ac_0  
rstudio                   1.1.383              h4814094_2  
ruamel_yaml               0.15.35          py36h1de35cc_1  
scikit-image              0.13.1           py36h1de35cc_1  
scikit-learn              0.19.1           py36hffbff8c_0  
scipy                     1.0.0            py36h1de22e9_0  
seaborn                   0.8.1            py36h595ecd9_0  
send2trash                1.4.2                    py36_0  
setuptools                39.0.1                    <pip>
setuptools                38.4.0                   py36_0  
simplegeneric             0.8.1                    py36_2  
singledispatch            3.4.0.3          py36hf20db9d_0  
sip                       4.19.8                    <pip>
sip                       4.18.1           py36h2824476_2  
six                       1.11.0           py36h0e22d5e_1  
snowballstemmer           1.2.1            py36h6c7b616_0  
sortedcollections         0.5.3            py36he9c3ed6_0  
sortedcontainers          1.5.9                    py36_0  
sphinx                    1.6.6                    py36_0  
Sphinx                    1.7.4                     <pip>
sphinxcontrib             1.0              py36h9364dc8_1  
sphinxcontrib-websupport  1.0.1            py36h92f4a7a_1  
spyder                    3.2.8                    py36_0  
spyder                    3.2.8                     <pip>
sqlalchemy                1.2.1            py36h1de35cc_0  
sqlite                    3.20.1                        0    conda-forge
statsmodels               0.8.0            py36h9c68fc9_0  
sympy                     1.1.1            py36h7f3cf04_0  
tblib                     1.3.2            py36hda67792_0  
terminado                 0.8.1                    py36_1  
testpath                  0.3.1            py36h625a49b_0  
tk                        8.6.7                h35a86e2_3  
toolz                     0.9.0                    py36_0  
tornado                   4.5.3                    py36_0  
traitlets                 4.3.2            py36h65bd3ce_0  
typing                    3.6.2            py36haa2d9ef_0  
unicodecsv                0.14.1           py36he531d66_0  
unixodbc                  2.3.4                h4cb4dde_1  
urllib3                   1.22             py36h68b9469_0  
wcwidth                   0.1.7            py36h8c6ec74_0  
webencodings              0.5.1            py36h3b9701d_1  
werkzeug                  0.14.1                   py36_0  
wheel                     0.30.0           py36h5eb2c71_1  
widgetsnbextension        3.1.0                    py36_0  
wrapt                     1.10.11          py36hc29e774_0  
xerces-c                  3.2.0                         0    conda-forge
xlrd                      1.1.0            py36h336f4a2_1  
xlsxwriter                1.0.2            py36h3736301_0  
xlwings                   0.11.5                   py36_0  
xlwt                      1.2.0            py36h5ad1178_0  
xz                        5.2.3                h0278029_2  
yaml                      0.1.7                hc338f04_2  
zeromq                    4.2.2                ha360ad0_2  
zict                      0.1.3            py36h71da714_0  
zlib                      1.2.11               hf3cbc9b
```

Somebody could help me please?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue on Mac OS High Sierra. After trying other solutions installing and upgrading packages I try back to stable version (and times when my code works :)) here is solution:

In terminal
1) go into your conda environment. Do it by activate conda environment:

```
source activate [your_environment_name]
```

2) Install gdal with defined libgdal:

```
conda install -c conda-forge gdal "libgdal<2.0"
```

For information: This solution I spot on [comment](https://github.com/conda-forge/fiona-feedstock/issues/13) done by dannguyen commented on May 22, 2016.